# How to delete Unwanted data in attendance with Multiple In/Out

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, time-and-attendance

How do i delete multiple records of attendance ? I have tried Several Queries to delete the Unwated data. also verify state identify

```
 0 = Time In and 1 = Time Out
```

This is the sample [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffe245cab0d8746f60e5a688111002e4)

Expected Output :

```
user_id        verify_date           verify_state   prev_state  next_state      TO_Date
14           2019-11-15 07:29:00         0               1         1       2019-11-15 19:12:00
15           2019-11-15 22:12:00         0               1         1       2019-11-16 06:29:00
```

Sample Query i have tried

```
delete from tbl_excel_attendance where CONCAT(User_id,verify_date) in (select  CONCAT(User_id,verify_date)  from
(select
A.*,
LAG(A.Verify_State) OVER (PARTITION BY A.User_id ORDER BY A.User_id, A.verify_date) as Prv_row_State,
LEAD(A.Verify_State) OVER (PARTITION BY A.User_id ORDER BY A.User_id, A.verify_date) as Nxt_row_State,
LEAD(A.verify_date) OVER (PARTITION BY A.User_id ORDER BY A.User_id, A.verify_date)  as TO_Date

from tbl_excel_attendance as A ) as X
where
(X.Prv_row_State = 1 and X.verify_state = 1 and  X.Nxt_row_State = 0) OR
(X.Prv_row_State = 1 and X.verify_state = 1 and  X.Nxt_row_State = 1 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Hour,X.verify_date,X.TO_Date)< 12.01) OR
(X.Prv_row_State = 0 and X.verify_state = 1 and  X.Nxt_row_State = 1 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(Hour,X.verify_date,X.TO_Date)< 12.01) OR
(X.Prv_row_State = 0 and X.verify_state = 0 and  X.Nxt_row_State = 1) OR
(X.Prv_row_State = 0 and X.verify_state = 0 and  X.Nxt_row_State = 0) OR
(X.Prv_row_State is null and X.verify_state = 1 and  X.Nxt_row_State = 1))
```

Which deletion of attendance base on my analysis

EDIT : Their Biometric is Door Access so it means if they need to go out they need to tap the biometric.

User id of 15 is a night shift.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: How do you know User id of 15 is a night shift? When does night shift start? You haven't stated what it is you are trying to achieve - looks like based on earliest and latest verify date for shift?

Comment: I'm basing it on the First in and last out  in verify date and i don't based it in Shifts.

Comment: Can you explain the logic for the different dates for user 15 ? I am unclear what should happen if comes back on shift '2019-11-16 22:12' or if changes shift pattern.

Comment: The verify date ``'2019-11-16 22:12'`` Is the First Time in on his attendance as you can see his verify_state is 0 = Time In and get the last verify_state = 1 which is ``2019-11-16 06:29`` = Time out